# Latest PhpStorm update: does it affect newly created Livewire components?

Tags: laravel, components, phpstorm, laravel-livewire

I updated to PhpStorm 2021.3 yesterday.  Has anyone else had a problem with any new Livewire components you have created after committing this update?

I created a pretty complex component and worked on it for a while before checking if it rendered.  And it did not.  Tried to find the error.  commented out a lot, still did not render.  So I created a vanilla Livewire component.

```
sail php artisan make:livewire general.EditSchool
```

`resources/views/livewire/general/edit-school.blade.php` has:

```html
<div>
    <p class="text-xl">
        If your happiness depends on money, you will never be happy with yourself.
    </p>
</div>
```

`app/Http/Livewire/General/EditSchool.php` has:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\General;

use Livewire\Component;

class EditSchool extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.general.edit-school');
    }
}
```

And I call it just below a working (older) Livewire component in an existing web page that works.:

```
@livewire('admin.users.header', ['user_id' => $user->id,
                                     'registrantOrAdmin' => $registrantOrAdmin])
@livewire('general.edit-school')
```

The `admin.users.header` component renders.  It craps out on the one I just created; `general.edit-school`.

If I put the `@livewire('general.edit-school')` before the working Livewire component, the page does not render.

If I take `@livewire('general.edit-school')` out of the web page, it works normally.

Is anyone else having trouble creating a Livewire component and having it render after the latest update?

BTW, I try

```
sail php artisan livewire:discover
```

and the manifest does not seem to be regenerated?  It only reports

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

This message is not new.  I usually get the Xdebug notice every time I issue a `sail php artisan` command.  But usually other things are reported having been done.

---

I have a thought this morning.

Livewire component:  `Groupmember.php`
Livewire blade:  `groupmember.blade.php`

When I started this extraction, I used the Project bar in PhpStorm, right clicked on the Livewire component `Groupmember.php` to Copy, then I right clicked on the containing folder to Paste and changed the name of the pasted file to `Groupmember_backup.php`, and did the same with the corresponding blade file.

I then proceeded to extract code from `Groupmember.php` and `groupmember.blade.php` to create a new Livewire component that would live inside of `groupmember.blade.php`.

Perhaps my copy and paste actions in PhpStorm project bar is the genesis of this entire problem?  If so how should I return to a normal state?  Perhaps VCS is the answer here.  I don't think I can solve it by copy and paste again, unless I use the refactor option within PhpStorm.

[image]

Comment: you say laravel update in the title but you talk about a PHPStorm update in the question

Comment: What do you mean by "does not render"? Are there exceptions, what does the actual generated html look like?

Comment: my apologies lagbox.  Hi Qire!  no, there are no exceptions.  500 server error.  The page stops rendering completely when it hits the @livewire() call in the blade component.  If there were a closing </select> tag just before the @livewire(), view page source would show the </select> tag and stop.  I turned on telescope, it returns nothing?  If I take the @livewire() out, telescope pumps out all the logging.  Mind you, this is doing this with NEW livewire components.  It does not behave this way with any livewire Component I created before today? or before the phpstorm update yesterday.

Comment: I do not see how PhpStorm can be at fault here: it does not run your code... and your `sail php artisan` commands fail. Must be the actual code: some updates there. DO you have any backups / VCS to get the older working copy and compare with the current one?

Comment: hi LazyOne.  Yes, I have VCS.  The trouble began ... well I decided to extract some coded into a component because I knew I would use it elsewhere in my app.  I extracted, and it did not work.  fair enough.  I commented the new livewire component out, page rendered properly so  it was in my extraction.  But when I made an entirely new livewire component and put it in the one I showed you above that was just a <p> tag, it did not work.  So I made another livewire comp contaiing a <p> tag and placed in another page.  no go. take it out, and page worked.   so there is where I am flumoxxed

Comment: This is of course in a docker environment.  I am wondering if docker and phpstorm and artisan tinker are not playing well together after the storm update.  the laravel manifest not being created on the discover command hints at that.

Comment: Try launching the affected version of your site without PhpStorm to check if the update has anything to do with it.

Comment: Hi, thx Dmitrii.  I think I found my error.  I copy and pasted files using the PhPStorm project column which screwed up the livewire manifest.  I should have used the artisan commands to create my components.  Instead, I copy and pasted the files to [filename_backup.php] and [filename.blade_backup.php].  I should have used sail php artisan livewire:make component and worked with the new files that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer.  I copy and pasted files in the phpstorm project bar.  So don't do that.

I have a thought this morning.

lwire component: Groupmember.php lwire blade: groupmember.blade.php

When I started this extraction, I used the Project bar in phpstorm, right clicked on the livewire component [Groupmember.php] to 'copy', then I right clicked on the containing folder to 'paste' and changed the name of the pasted file to Groupmember_backup.php, and did the same with the corresponding blade file.

I then proceeded to extract code from Groupmember.php and groupmember.blade.php to create a new livewire component that would live inside of groupmember.blade.php.

Perhaps my copy and paste actions in the php storm project bar is the genesis of this entire problem? If so how should I return to a normal state? perhaps vcs is the answere thre. I don't think I can solve it by copy and paste again, unless I use the refactor option within phpstorm.

Comment: The recent 2021.3 has finally implemented Move Namespace refactoring on DnD (Drag and Drop). Could it be that it also affects your Copy & Paste? Without knowing all the details/trying here myself -- not sure. https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/12/phpstorm-2021-3-release/#move_class_and_move_namespace_refactorings_with_drag_and_drop

Comment: You can use **Local History** to roollback to a previous saved copy (unless you have reinstalled the IDE or rebuilt indexes after that.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html

Comment: LazyOne.  thx.  not sure.  I will read your suggested link as well.

Comment: btw, I did roll back to a day before the copy and paste, and then used the refactor menu to safe delete the files I had changed.  I then created  new livewire components with slightly different names and worked the extraction that way instead with copy and pasted files, and now I am back at it.  My extraction is working.

So I suppose the lesson is that do not use the phpstorm project bar to copy and paste files.  Continue to use the right click to refactor menu and go about it that way.